# Visual Studio Code with XDebug Getting Stuck

Tags: visual-studio-code, xdebug

I'm using XDebug with Visual Studio Code on Windows 10 to debug PHP.

The debugger works but from time to time it's getting stuck (hits the breakpoint but doesn't respond to step in, step over commands).

I tried switching to XDebug nts version (Not Thread Safe) but it doesn't help. Restarting the web server (Apache) doesn't resolve it either. Sometimes computer restart helps but not always...

Any solution or workaround? (Even a command line that frees this deadlock)

Comment: Oh! I Think I found it. Having out of context debug expressions in the watch window causing the debugger to get stuck...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Having out of context debug expressions in the watch window causing the debugger to get stuck.
You should clear the watch window from expressions.
I guess the evaluation of out of context expressions make the debugger to get stuck.

Comment: After scratching my head all day finally, it worked! Thank for your answer :D

Comment: Wow, that is a horrible behavior/glitch. This solved it for me as well after days of wondering what was going on (and essentially stopping using XDebug).